# Selecting specific cells from multiple tables

Tags: sql

I am trying to select specific cells from 3 different tables.

I have 3 different queries but whenever I run them it crashes a while and I was wondering if maybe I could combine them into one query.

```
SELECT * FROM INFM_DALI_BBM_CSC2.MARA_BBM 
    WHERE MANDT = '011' 
    AND MTART IN ('HALB','FERT') 
    AND "/RB04/YERZKENNZ" in ('EZ','BG','TS') 
    AND LOGSYS in ('SAPP72011', 'SAPPOE011');

SELECT * FROM INFM_DALI_BBM_CSC2.MARC_BBM 
    WHERE MANDT = '011' 
    AND BESKZ IN ('E','F') 
    AND WERKS in ('8640','864W','E499') 
    AND LOGSYS in ('SAPP72011', 'SAPPOE011');

SELECT * FROM INFM_DALI_BBM_CSC2.MBEW_BBM 
    WHERE MANDT = '011' 
    AND BKLAS IN ('7900','7920') 
    AND LOGSYS in ('SAPP72011', 'SAPPOE011');
```

The table should get the values that are on this table.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TSFJbpBsPJ5ZG61ULX6WumdNt1DUPJXO/view?usp=sharing

Comment: please provide a sample of the tables

Comment: Are you sure about "/RB04/YERZKENNZ" ?? Is it a column name ?

Comment: What is this?  `"/RB04/YERZKENNZ" in ('EZ','BG','TS') `?

Comment: "/RB04/YERZKENNZ"  is a column

Comment: @GJCode I posted a link of an image of the table

Answer (score 0):

Consider this :

```
SELECT * FROM INFM_DALI_BBM_CSC2.MARA_BBM 
 WHERE MANDT = '011'
   AND LOGSYS IN ('SAPP72011', 'SAPPOE011')  
   AND ( ( MTART IN ('HALB','FERT') AND "/RB04/YERZKENNZ" IN ('EZ','BG','TS') ) OR 
         ( BESKZ IN ('E','F') AND WERKS IN ('8640','864W','E499')             ) OR 
         ( BKLAS IN ('7900','7920')                                           ) )
```